# Ways to retrieve user accounts' last signed in date with provisioning API

Tags: php, google-apps, provisioning, user-accounts

There are currently 90,000 user accounts under my domain, and I have been manually deleting inactive accounts but it seems unproductive and a waste of time. I want to make use of provisioning API to delete these accounts, but I can't seem to find a way to retrieve the user accounts' last signed in date (to identify which are the inactive ones). Are there any methods which allows me to retrieve the last signed in dates of all user accounts? Thank you.

Ks

Answer (score 0):

instead of the Provisioning API you can use the [Reporting API](http://code.google.com/intl/en/googleapps/domain/reporting/google_apps_reporting_api.html#Accounts_Report), specifically the User accounts report, which includes a column for last login date. You can also generate the activity report that shows the number of accounts active and idle for several periods of time. You can use the Reporting API from PHP code using the client library

Answer (score 0):

To delete inactive accounts, you'll use the [Reporting API](http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/reporting/google_apps_reporting_api.html) in tandem with the Provisioning API. With the Reporting API, pull an 'accounts' report. There is a column last_login_date, which you can use to identify inactive users -- these users you can batch delete using the Provisioning API.